# How much memory to multiply int by a double?

Tags: c, memory

How much memory does multiplying 16 bit unsigned integer by a double and assigning it to another unsigned 16 bit integer take in C?  Would it temporarily load the double result in a register before assigning it to int?  I'm doing some programming for embedded systems that's why I'm asking.

```
u16int_t a = 3;
u16int_t b = a * .4;
```

Comment: Noone knows. Compiler & arch specific.

Comment: You can try generating the assembly code for your specific architecture and reading it. I agree with tilz0R that it's arch dependant

Comment: Agreed, and to be precise, any modern optimizing compiler would reduce that specific code to a compile-time constant. Nothing would even go into a register. The multiplication would be done at compile-time. (And even that might not be done if `b` isn't used.) But it depends on your actual code, your architecture, your compiler, and the compiler settings.

Comment: As pointed out before, it really depends on a lot of factors. Local variables are put on the stack, unless they can be optimised into registers. Constants are optimized away at compile time, as @RobNapier pointed out. 
The interesting cases are when optimization level is low (-O0), the vars are actually function parameters (not constants/locals), when the function is inline-able, when the arch doesnt natively support float/double, etc.

Comment: @RobNapier: A compiler would generate the multiplication (or some other floating-point operation) if it supports IEEE-754 semantics, as the operation raises the inexact flag.

Comment: It depends upon computer architecture

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm unclear how that applies to this case. Can you explain a little more? `clang -O` (which I believe supports IEEE-754 semantics, correct?) optimizes this to `movl $1, %esi` on x64  (I tested with `printf("%d", b);`). That's exactly what I expected when writing the comment. Is there a deeper point I'm missing?

Comment: @RobNapier: IEEE-754 specifies exceptions that may occur during floating-point operations and status flags that record whether they have occurred. One of those exceptions is *inexact*. It is signaled if the result of an operation differs from what it would have been if the precision and the exponent range were unbounded. If a compiler truly supports IEEE-754 arithmetic, then `3*.4` should signal inexact, and, with default exception handling, the inexact flag should be raised. (“Signal“ and “exception” are in the IEEE-754 meaning, not the C/C++ meaning.)

Comment: @RobNapier: You can see that `3*.4` is inexact with `3*.4-1 - fma(3, .4, -1)`. It evaluates to non-zero, but would be zero if `3*.4` were exact. (`fma` is declared in `<math.h>`.) (This presumes IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point for `double`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The computation itself uses very little memory, if any at all since in this particular piece of code, the result can be computed at compile time.

More generally, if the code fragment is the only place in your software where you use floating point arithmetics, depending on the actual embedded system characteristics, the code fragment might cause runtime library code to be linked for floating point support, which may amount to several kilobytes of code added to your binary file.

To avoid this, you could use use integer arithmetics:

```
u16int_t a = 3;
u16int_t b = a * 4 / 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

Run 2*`sizeof(double)` to find out. The code needs a temporary to store (double)a as an implicit cast and another to store `.4`. Typically there will be two free register available and the actual cost is zero, but there might not be.

Note that this memory is allocated on the stack, so the effective cost of the memory is probably zero. The compiler is really good at reusing temporary memory slots, and this is unlikely to be where your deepest stack depth is.

If `u16int_t a = 3` really is a constant piece of code and not an artifact of reduction, the compiler will optimize the whole thing away to `u16int_t b = floating point constant` and again allocates zero bytes for the multiply.

Comment: You should also mention that embedded CPUs often don't include hardware floating point instructions.  On such CPUs, if the multiplication cannot be performed at compile time, the compiler will have to emit library routines to do the multiplication and conversions into the compiled program.  The space occupied by these routines is likely to be the biggest memory cost of the operation.

Comment: @zwol: If it is such a CPU, we have no hope of answering the question without knowing which CPU, so ...

Comment: We can't say exactly how big the library routines are without knowing which CPU and which compiler, but we _can_ say that on a CPU without hardware float, software float routines must be used, and will be considerably larger than `2*sizeof(double)`.